# Combine a single dataframe(left) with multiple dataframes within a list (right)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, data-cleaning

I have a list of dataframes. each of which holds 2 columns 'Key and Value' and then I have a main dataframe that holds all the keys that exist in the dataframes in the list.

I wanted to left join all of the dfs in the list with the main dataframe without using a long syntax.

```
df_main.merge(df_list[0], on='key_0', how='left').merge(df_list[1], on='key_1', 
how='left').merge(df_list[2], on='key_2', how='left').....
```

This approach would be fine with a couple of tables in the list but not scalable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: if they have common columns, then you can set the columns as index and join on the index

Comment: you can try `pd.concat((df_main.merge(y,on=f'key_{x}',how='left') for x,y in enumerate(df_list)))`

Comment: Simply `concat` all dfs in list and then `merge` to main without any loop.